Why can't I assign a member function pointer to an overloaded function without using a type alias?
See below example. Can't think of a reason why this is not possible. Am I really forced to introduce a using decl or typedef? Any other reasonable workarounds?
struct Foo {
    public:
        int get_res() { return 1; }
        int get_res(int i) { return 1; }
};


// Works!
struct Accessor {
    using overload = int(Foo::*)();
    static constexpr overload resGetter = &Foo::get_res;
};

// error: expected unqualified-id before ')' token
struct Accessor {
    static constexpr int(Foo::*)() resGetter = &Foo::get_res;
};


Don't get me started on how screwy this looks, but static constexpr int(Foo::*resGetter)()  = &Foo::get_res;

The syntax is a left-over from C, int(*resGetter)() is the free function version, and the brackets are most likely there because otherwise there's no way in the general case to tell int*resGetter() from a function returning a pointer to an int, and likely no one could figure out how to get int() resGetter to parse without breaking something else. No matter how crazy things look, there was always a good reason for the insanity. Even if the insanity resulted from the limitations of the tools and hardware available in the 1970s.

Some really handy reading if you want to keep going down this rabbit hole: https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/pointers-to-members

Related: What's the syntax for declaring an array of function pointers without using a separate typedef?

You have a typo. The name resGetter should go just after the * in int(Foo::*)(). See this answer in the dupe: How can I define a class member as a pointer

struct Accessor2 {
    static constexpr int(Foo::*resGetter)() = &Foo::get_res;
};

That's why you don't usually write member function pointers like this -- it looks strange, and people make errors.
Typedefs do not generate any code -- you can use them as much as you want to make your code readable.

Thanks, the intent is to use this in a long set of template specializations that are exposed in a header, and aliases in headers seems to be a cargo-culted sin I can't commit.

"aliases in headers seems to be a cargo-culted sin" - citation required

frankly, "aliases in headers seems to be a cargo-culted sin" sounds like cargo cult

"Never declare namespace aliases or convenience using-declarations at namespace scope in header files, only in .cc files." And I would consider this the convenience category.
From:
"https://abseil.io/tips/119#:~:text=The%20Problem,the%20use%20of%20relative%20qualifiers."

Everything is a sin unless you have a good reason for it not to be.

Arguably, most of my typedefs from headers are in classes, not namespaces -- but in general, I wouldn't worry about some rule that someone made up. If it improves an API, I do whatever works.

@fyodor-the-ignorant the article you link doesnt mention type aliases. Its about using declarations for whole namespaces and namespace aliases. Though the google guideline linked from there gives the rationale "Like other declarations, aliases declared in a header file are part of that header's public API..." and if that is what you want then go for it. The google guideline is only about not making it part of the public API when it should not be part of the public API. I disagree with many items in the google guide, but it is cool that they provide pro and con so you can make your decision

@fyodor-the-ignorant the google guide even has postive examples for which they encourage to declare it in a header.

Looping back around to this: yes, the pertinent part was actually about these aliases being declared as part of a public API (https://google.github.io/styleguide/cppguide.html#Aliases). In my case these aliases are exclusively internal details and polluting the public API with names that shouldn't be used by clients is messy, and we're left with only cons at that point.
